# Add a class to a markdown code block

Tags: php, markdown

I am using a https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown to convert markdown to html, and I can't find any information on this, but how can I add a class to a code block?

I am running the following:

```
$html = Markdown::defaultTransform($value);
return $html;
```

To parse something that looks like this:

```
My Paragraph

    if($something){
        // Do something here
    }
```

Most of the examples I have seen add `{.test}` to the end which adds the class so I tried that and nothing happend. I tried the beginning as well and still nothing.

Tried this:

```
    if($something){
        // Do something here
    }
{.test}
```

And This:

```
{.test}
    if($something){
        // Do something here
    }
```

How can I add a class with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hopefully I didn't miss the scope of the question - it was a little ambiguous, I hadn't realised it might not be until I had already written this*

To add a new class using the class functionality you want to `extend` the class

Extending a class allows you to copy the existing functionality and add your own extended functionality (as per the name!)

Extending looks like  this
`class MardownExtended extends Markdown {`

From here you can add your own method

```
public static function myParagraph() { 
    // ...
}
```

You will want to use the class MarkdownExtended in your code, rather than the original class

`MarkdownExtended::myParagraph();`

Comment: `MarkdownExtra` Is what I needed to use. And what I wanted was built into it!